# laravel 5.2 очередь

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq

Очередь в laravel возвратила:

```
{ job: 'Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call',
  data: 
   { commandName: 'App\\Jobs\\SendReminderData',
     command: 'O:25:"App\\Jobs\\SendReminderData":5:{s:4:"user";s:5:"tests";s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";s:11:"messages.ex";s:5:"delay";N;s:6:"\u0000*\u0000job";N;}' } }
```

Код:

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
class SendReminderData extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
    public $user;
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function handle()
    {

    }
}
```

Я не могу понять что за информацию оно выводит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал это вот так.

```
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$data = "info: Hello World!";
$msg = new AMQPMessage($data);
$channel->basic_publish($msg, 'messages.ex');
echo " [x] Sent ", $data, "\n";
$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```